# dropdownlist inside a modal in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have select option (dropdown list) inside a modal in which the option are getting printed below the dropdownlist... I tried checking if the code works if i redirect the page and works, like the options are inside the dropdown box but same thing inside modal doesn't work? Any solutions would be helpful.

[image: modal]
[image: redirected page]
add_details.blade

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

            <div>

                <h2>Enter Your Details</h2>
                <form action="{{ route('save') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <span style="color:black">
                                <select class="form-control" name="collegeID" id="college_name" required />
                                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select College</option>
                                @foreach ($college_names as $college_name)
                                <option value="{{$college_name->collegeID}}">
                                    {{ $college_name->college_name }}
                                </option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <br />




                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="Cbse" name="regno">

                            <label for="" style="color:black">CBSE</label>
                            <input type="radio" value="State" name="regno"> <label style="color:black">PUC</label>
                            <input type="radio" value="State" name="regno"> <label style="color:black">State</label>

                            <div id="showCbse" class="myDiv">
                                <label for="regno" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Admission Number</span></label>
                                <input type="number" name="regno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter valid Admission Number" />
                                @if ($errors->has('regno'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('regno') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div id="showState" class="myDiv">
                                <label for="regno" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Register Number</span></label>
                                <input type="number" name="regno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter valid Register Number" />
                                @if ($errors->has('regno'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('regno') }}</span>
                                @endif

                            </div>



                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <label for="name" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Name</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{old('name')}}" placeholder="Enter Name" required />

                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block font-red-mint">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @endif
            </div>
            <div>
                </br>
                <label for="address" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Address</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="address" value="{{old('address')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address" required />

                @if ($errors->has('address'))
                <span class="help-block font-red-mint">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div>
                </br>
                <label for="yop" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Year Of Passing</span></label>
                <input type="date" name="yop" value="{{old('yop')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Year Of Passing" required />

                @if ($errors->has('yop'))
                <span class="help-block font-red-mint">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('yop') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div>
                </br>
                <label for="email" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Email</span></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" required />

                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block font-red-mint">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div>
                </br>
                <label for="phone" class="form-label"><span style="color:black">Phone Number</span></label>
                <input type="number" name="phone" value="{{old('phone')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" required />

                @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                <span class="help-block font-red-mint">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <br /> <br />
            <div class="col-md-4">
                </br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

                </form>
                <a href="users1" class="menu-link"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button></a>



            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .myDiv {
                display: none;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                    var demovalue = $(this).val();
                    $("div.myDiv").hide();
                    $("#show" + demovalue).show();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

add.blade (page where the modal pops up)

```
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/r-2.2.3/datatables.min.css" />
    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    @extends('auth.dashboard')
    @section('title')
    Dashboard
    @endsection
    @section('body')
    
    @if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        {{Session::get('success')}}
    </div>
    @elseif(Session::has('failed'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        {{Session::get('failed')}}
    </div>
    @endif


<body>
</br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">

                        <div>
            <div class="pull-right">
          
            <a class="btn btn-primary" title="Add" 
              href="{{route('add_details')}}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>

<a class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal" data-attr="{{ route('add_details')}}" title="Add Institute Details"> ADD
</a>

            </div>
            </br>
        </br>
    </br>
             
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered user_datatable" id="user_datatable">
            <thead class="thead-dark div-2">
           <tr>
                       
           <center>  <th><strong><span style="color:white">ID</span></strong></th> </center>
                        <th><strong><span style="color:white">Name</span></strong></th>
                        <th><span style="color:white">Status</span></th>
                        <th width="15%"><span style="color:white">Action</span></th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
              

                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- medium modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/r-2.2.3/datatables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.noConflict();
        fill_datatable();


        function fill_datatable(collegeID = '') {
            var table = $('.user_datatable').DataTable({
                order: [
                    [0, 'desc']
                ],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('alumni.datatable') }}",
                    data: {
                        collegeID: collegeID
                    }

                },
                columns: [{
                        data: 'id',
                        name: 'id'
                    },

                    {
                        data: 'name',
                        name: 'name'
                    },
                   
                    {
                        data: 'status',
                        name: 'status',
                        mRender: function(data) {
                            if (data == '1') {
                                return '<center><span class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" > Pending </span></center>'
                            }
                            if (data == '0') {
                                return '<center><span class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" > Approved </span></center>'
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    {
                                data: 'action',
                                name: 'action',
                                orderable: false,
                                searchable: false
                            },

                ]
            });
        }
        $('#filter').click(function() {

            var collegeID = $('#college_name').val();

            if (collegeID != '') {
                $('#user_datatable').DataTable().destroy();
                fill_datatable(collegeID);
            } else {
                alert('Select Both filter option');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    // display a modal (medium modal)
    $(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            // return the result
            success: function(result) {
                $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
                $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();

            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
            timeout: 8000
        })
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Unrelated: that's a lot of different Bootstrap, Jquery and Datatables versions you're using

Comment: Agree.. but if I remove some similar scripts of diff versions, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: you added /> at end of opening <select> tag. i.e. <input /> is both opening and closing tag. You did the same with <select />

Comment: Thanks a lot.. was trying for days, it worked finally. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's minor mistake all devs do :D , I also did this type of mistake.

use

```
<select class="form-control" name="collegeID" id="college_name" required>
```

Instead of this

```
<select class="form-control" name="collegeID" id="college_name" required />
```

Just remove close tag from end of the start tag.